# What does "DMA: Out of SW-IOMMU space" error mean?

Tags: linux, kernel, hardware, error-handling

First the link: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1060268

Since this affects the kernel and other Distros, what does this type of error mean and why it happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your PC has more than 4 GB of memory, but has also some devices that support only 32-bit addresses, any I/O from or to these devices must be mapped to somewhere in the low 4 GB range.

Typically, a range of 64 MB is allocated for this.

"Out of SW-IOMMU space" means that either

1. you are doing so much I/O that you need more than 64 MB of buffers at the same time; or
2. some driver is buggy and forgets to deallocate its buffers after it's done using them.

Your symptoms indicate that you are suffering from problem 2.